# putting output of command into a string

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to store the output of a bash command to a string in a bash script. The part that matters is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
player_status="$(playerctl -l)"
```

The output of the command when run on terminal (not with the bash script) is "No players were found". When I run the bash script (note that there is not an echo) it outputs "No players were found" to the terminal. I want it instead to not put it in the terminal but instead the variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like your command is producing output to standard error rather than standard output. Try using the `2>&1` modifier on your shell command.

```
#!/bin/bash
player_status="$(playerctl -l 2>&1)"
```

The modifier means "send standard error to standard output."

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use   backquotes  (   `   ), backquotes execute the command and return the output in the same shell LEVEL

```
player_status=`playerctl -l`
```

instead of

```
player_status="$(playerctl -l)"   # Here the command is executed in child process thus its output is not available in this script from which CHILD process was executed
```